# JsonProperty is getting ignored in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to change my json response _sddInfo to dropOffShippingInfo but below **@JsonProperty** getting ignored. How can I solve this issue?

```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class EligibleShippingMethods implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @JsonProperty("dropOffShippingInfo")
        private DropOffShippingInfo _sddInfo;
    
        public DropOffShippingInfo get_sddInfo() {
            return _sddInfo;
        }
    
        public void set_sddInfo(DropOffShippingInfo _sddInfo) {
            this._sddInfo = _sddInfo;
        }

}
```

### response

```
"eligibleShippingMethods": [
        "_sddInfo": {
          "startTime": "2020-08-21T15:00:00Z",
          "endTime": "2020-08-21T17:00:00Z",
          "customerScheduleType": "window"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Try putting the annotation on the getter method. Better yet, don't use bad naming for fields like that. Java naming convention, which the JSON processor expects, is for field names to start with lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

In the past Jackson may have supported one name for serialization and another for deserialization. Not anymore. Therefore, you should annotate a getter  with `@JsonProperty("dropOffShippingInfo")`, it expects the incoming json payload to also have `dropOffShippingInfo`

Comment: @AbhiRam What versions of Jackson and Spring you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonProperty("dropOffShippingInfo")` to getter method and make sure you are importing right package `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class EligibleShippingMethods implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DropOffShippingInfo _sddInfo;

    @JsonProperty("dropOffShippingInfo")
    public DropOffShippingInfo get_sddInfo() {
        return _sddInfo;
    }

    public void set_sddInfo(DropOffShippingInfo _sddInfo) {
        this._sddInfo = _sddInfo;
    }

}
```